# Using Centroid decomposition instead of SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, svd

This [paper](http://jblevins.org/research/centroid/updating.pdf) says centroid decomposition (CD) is an approximation to singular value decomposition (SVD). First I do not understand CD yet, since code is available I just want to try it out how it works but I cannot figure out how to use it, it looks preety much different than SVD. Given a CD how do I get left/right singular vectors and singular values which I can use in my code?

Comment: [Here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~mtchu/Research/Papers/centroid.pdf) is another paper on the CD. The main idea seems to be to maximize $x^\top A^\top A x$ not for all possible vectors, but only for $x \in \{0,1\}^n$.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1137/S0895479800382555 useful paper. I plan to come back to this question later this summer.